# How to use scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator with own triangulation

Tags: scipy, scipy-spatial

I have [my own triangulation algorithm](https://github.com/python-adaptive/adaptive/blob/master/adaptive/learner/triangulation.py) that creates a triangulation based on both Delaunay's condition and the gradient such that the triangles align with the gradient.

This is an example output:
[image]

The above description is not relevant to the question but is necessary for the context.

Now I want to use my triangulation with `scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator` to do an interpolation.

With scipy's Delaunay I would do the following

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate
import scipy.spatial
points = np.random.rand(100, 2)
values = np.random.rand(100)
delaunay = scipy.spatial.Delaunay(points)
ip = scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(delaunay, values)
```

This `delaunay` object has `delaunay.points` and `delaunay.simplices` that form the triangulation. I have the exact same information with my own  triangulation, but `scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator` requires a `scipy.spatial.Delaunay` object.

I think I would need to subclass `scipy.spatial.Delaunay` and implement the relevant methods. However, I don't know which ones I need in order to get there.

Comment: [`LinearNDInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html) also accepts an array of points as its first argument.

Comment: I know but that would result in a new triangulation using scipy.spatial.Delaunay, which is not what I want.

Comment: Ah, right. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrbybKWwb7c

Comment: I have the same problem, and I do not think there is any development on Scipy side to provide the feature. I have tried to create a dummy Delaunay object and to modify the content of its attributes, but I got `AttributeError: can't set attribute`. On the bright side, if you are working in 2D, Matplotlib provides the feature. Create the triangulation object with [Triangulation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/tri_api.html#matplotlib.tri.Triangulation) and interpolate with [CubicTriInterpolator](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/tri_api.html#matplotlib.tri.CubicTriInterpolator).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do this very same thing with the Delaunay triangulation offered by the [`triangle` package](https://github.com/drufat/triangle). The triangle Delaunay code is about eight times faster than the SciPy one on large (~100_000) points. (I encourage other developers to try to beat that :) )

Unfortunately, the [`Scipy LinearNDInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html) function relies heavily on specific attributes present in the SciPy Delaunay triangulation object. These are created by the [`_get_delaunay_info()`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/3e968dc661ede52495aba0bbc76639b3ddfdf8f7/scipy/spatial/qhull.pyx#L2216) CPython code, which is difficult to disassemble. Even knowing which attributes are needed (there seem to be many, including things like `paraboloid_scale` and `paraboloid_shift`), I'm not sure how I would extract this from a different triangulation library.

Instead, I tried @Patol75's approach (comment to the Question above), but using [`LinearTriInterpolator`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/tri_api.html#matplotlib.tri.LinearTriInterpolator) instead of the Cubic one. The code runs correctly, but is slower than doing the entire thing in SciPy. Interpolating 400_000 points from a cloud of 400_000 points takes about 3 times longer using the matplotlib code than scipy. The [Matplotlib tri code is written in C++](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/master/src/tri), so converting the code to i.e. CuPy is not straightforward. If we could mix the two approaches, we could reduce the total time from 3.65 sec / 10.2 sec to 1.1 seconds!

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
N = 400_000
shape = (100, 100)
points = np.random.random((N, 2)) * shape # spread over 100, 100 to avoid float point errors
vals = np.random.random((N,))
interp_points1 = np.random.random((N,2)) * shape
interp_points2 = np.random.random((N,2)) * shape

triangle_input = dict(vertices=points)

### Matplotlib Tri
import triangle as tr
from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation, LinearTriInterpolator

triangle_output = tr.triangulate(triangle_input) # 280 ms
tri = tr.triangulate(triangle_input)['triangles'] # 280 ms
tri = Triangulation(*points.T, tri) # 5 ms
func = LinearTriInterpolator(tri, vals) # 9490 ms
func(*interp_points.T).data # 116 ms
# returns [0.54467719, 0.35885304, ...]
# total time 10.2 sec

### Scipy interpolate
tri = Delaunay(points) # 2720 ms
func = LinearNDInterpolator(tri, vals) # 1 ms
func(interp_points) # 925 ms

# returns [0.54467719, 0.35885304, ...]
# total time 3.65 sec
```